# Apache redirect with HSTS

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, redirect, hsts

I need to redirect all for `example.com` to `https://www.example.com` with HSTS turned on. How to do it? I got configuration in vhost80 and vhost443. What to fix in this code:

in vhost 80

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

in vhost 443

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have just two vHost containers. One for port 80 and handles requests to both `example.com` and `www.example.com` only and the other for port 443 that again handles both `example.com` and `www.example.com` only. Then...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.example.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

You simply need to remove all the conditions, only the `RewriteRule` directive is required. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

You also need to ensure you redirect to the same hostname, hence the use of `HTTP_HOST`, not `SERVER_NAME`. (Although, by default, `SERVER_NAME` is the same as `HTTP_HOST` - but this depends on the `UseCanonicalName` directive in your server config.)

The rule in the vHost 443 container looks "OK".

However, best practise would avoid the use of mod_rewrite altogether... create a separate vHost for each hostname and use the simpler mod_alias `Redirect` directive instead.

Comment: So, does not HTTP_HOST redirect AliasName also? You mentioned to use separated hostname files for example and www.example domains?
In last example ```RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]``` how to add here also servername.example.com ?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's the simpler [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) alternative suggested by MrWhite. This also has the HSTS headers in the correct place and, as recommendable, subdomains included & with preloading. First the three redirecting virtual hosts and then the actual virtual host serving content.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

    # The mandatory SSL* directives.

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # The mandatory SSL* directives.
    # . . . whatever else you may have here

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</VirtualHost>
```

Naturally, this requires both mod_alias and [mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html) loaded. Wrapping the `Header` directives inside `<IfModule>` sections would avoid errors on missing mod_headers module, but then you would not have HSTS enabled, and this was titled as redirection with HSTS.

---

The two `<VirtualHost *:80>` blocks are there because:

- there's a limitation: you can't use the variable `%{SERVER_NAME}` with `Redirect`.
- with HSTS it's recommended to redirect first to the HTTPS and then to the canonical name.

**For the wildcard `*.example.com` redirection** I'd add a `ServerAlias` to the `VirtualHosts *:80` redirecting first to the domain apex and then again there on the HTTPS. As the `www` is included in the `*.example.com`, you won't even need the additional `<VirtualHost *:80>` for it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
    . . .
```

This way the user...

1. Enters URL `http://anysub.example.com/`.
2. Gets redirected to `https://example.com/` (or is already on the same configuration, if entered `https://anysub.example.com/`, or if the HSTS policy is already in the cache).
3. Sees the HSTS header, protecting all `(*.)*.example.com` including `anysub.example.com`.
4. Gets finally redirect to the canonical `https://www.example.com/`.

Comment: SO as i understand, its better to use 2 times VH direction not AliasName?

Comment: And what about ```*.example.com``` wildcard redirection ?

Comment: As this would have been too complex to answer in the comments, I've answered both these questions on my edit.

Comment: Another question, how can i test it from my server or web? I use this page: ```https://httpstatus.io/ ``` and it shows http to https redirect first and than to httpswww. As i understand, with HSTS it seems ok. How can i also test it if HSTS is working propably and redirections too. At this moment i do not use mod_alias just redirect rule without conditions. But i want to test it and learn how to do it and how it works. curl ?

Comment: The `Redirect` is a directive from mod_alias, so by using it you are using mod_alias. You could test the responses with `curl`, and the browser behavior regarding HSTS with the developer tools in the browser.